# Obtaining quotient with remainder using just arithmetic operators

Tags: c++, math, operators

I'm just starting to learn some basics of C++ but i'm stumbled upon a issue.

For example, I'm trying to convert celcius to fahrenheit.

Assuming, I only have this fixed formula.

```
F = 9/5(c) + 32
```

I'm aware that mathematically it is possible to break it down to

```
Mathematically : (9c/5) + 32
```

however, i'll not be able to obtain a quotient with the reminder

So how exactly do i obtain both quotient with reminder using just arithmetic operators or is it impossible

I tested out but it still refuses to give me the correct output

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

double f;
int c;

cout<<"Enter degree celcius:"<<endl;
cin>>c;
cout<<endl;

f = 9/5 * c + 32; //incorrect ways for obvious reason
f = 9%5 * c + 32; //incorrect ways for obvious reason

cout<<c<<"degree celcius is equals to:"<<f<<endl;

}
```

Comment: What relevance do you believe the remainder of such an operation would hold?

Comment: Are you asking how you you get a floating point number doing `9/5 * c + 32`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes with just using arithmetic operators.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i believe is to convert any integers using simple arithmetic operator

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question. *Why would the "remainder" of a temperature conversion be of any use to anyone anywhere?*

Comment: i'm just trying to get the remainder of that fraction to multiply it together with the celcius to produce the fahrenheit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> f = 9/5 * c + 32; //incorrect ways for obvious reason
> ```

If you knew the "obvious reason" why this was incorrect, you wouldn't be asking this question!

It is actually incorrect because it does the calculation with *integer* values. `9`, `5`, `c`, and `32` are all `int`s, and when you do mathematical operations with `int`s, C++ gives you the result as an `int`. Because integers are whole numbers, they do not have a decimal portion and cannot store a remainder.

After the calculation is done, you *assign* the result to `f`, which is a `double`. Although floating-point types have a decimal portion that can store the remainder, all you've done here is convert the integer result to a floating-point value.

You can think of your code as being equivalent to:

```
int result = 9/5 * c + 32;
f = static_cast<double>(result);
```

In order to fix the problem, you need to force the calculation to be done as floating-point:

```
f = 9.0/5.0 * static_cast<double>(c) + 32.0;
```

This will preserve the "remainder" as the decimal portion of the floating-point value, `f`.

Technically, all you need is for a single intermediate operation to yield a floating-point result. If the first operation results in a floating-point value, all remaining operands will be promoted to floating-point to match this initial operand. So you could simply do:

```
f = 9.0/5 * c + 32;
```

(`9.0` is a double literal, just like `9` is an integer literal. Adding the decimal portion (`.x`) is what turns it into a double. If you had written `9.0f`, that would be a float literal.)

Comment: but for example if my formula insist on being an integer 9/5, is it possible to still return the results as above?

Comment: @teo Sort of. You can do `9/5 * static_cast<double>(c) + 32`, but the problem is that `9/5` == 1 (not 1.8). There is nothing you can do about that. One integer divided by another always gives an integer result.

Answer (score 3):

The literals `9` and `5` both have type `int`, so the expression `9/5` will also produce a value of type `int`.   That means rounding toward zero, so produces the value `1`.

Essentially, to get the results you expect, you need to use floating point.

For example;

```
 f = 9.0/5.0*c + 32;
```

`9.0` and `5.0` are both of type `double`, so the division produces a result of type `double` (equal to `1.8`).   Since `1.8` is of type `double`, `c` is then promoted to `double` before doing the multiplication.   The result of the multiplication is of type `double`, so `32` is also promoted to `double` before adding it.

Comment: so simply saying, to avoid such issue, i would just have to declare any number as float since my formula contains a fraction which returns a float value.

Comment: but for example if my formula insist on being an integer 9/5, is it possible to still return the results as above?

Comment: A formula does not "insist on being an integer 9/5".   If you are implementing a formula in a programming language, you need to express that formula in a way that works as required.   In C++, that means taking into account that dividing, adding, multiplying, or subtracting two values of type `int` produces an `int`, not a `double`.   If you want a floating point result, either literal values need to be expressed as floating point (e.g. `9.0` rather than `9`) or values of type `int` need to be explicitly converted (e.g. `static_cast<double>(9)`).

Answer (score 2):

To get a floating point number out of

```
9/5 * c + 32
```

Then one of the values of the division needs to be a floating point literal.  This will cause the result of the division to be a floating point value which in turn will cause the rest of the expression to be a floating point value.  We can do this by using

```
f = 9.0/5 * c + 32;
```

Adding the `.0` cause the literal to become a `double` instead of it being a `int`.

Comment: but for example if my formula insist on being an integer 9/5, is it possible to still return the results as above?

Answer (score 1):

Your factors are ints so the result will be an int.

Instead of `9/5 * c + 32` try `9.0/5.0 * c + 32`

You may also want to declare c as a double.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the quotient and remainder of the division operation will not assist you to calculate the Fahrenheit equivalent of Celsius, but in general the quotient and remainder can be calculated like this:

```
int dividend = 123;
int divisor = 5;
int quotient = dividend / divisor;    // integer division
int remainder = dividend % divisor;    // use modulo operation to get remainder
cout << "quotient = " << quotient << ", remainer = " << remainder << endl;

# quotient = 24, remainer = 3
```

To get Fahrenheit as a double:

```
double fahrenheit = 9/5.0 * c + 32;    // uses floating point division
```

Using `5.0` forces the use of floating point for the calculations.

Comment: I'm like just trying to obtain the value of 9/5 which is 1.8 via arithmetic operator but it either returns you a 1 with the operator "/" or 4 with the operator "%"

Comment: Because you are doing _integer division_, as stated in virtually every answer given to your question. The decimal 1.8 _equals_ the fraction 1 4/5 (one and four fifths) which is what the quotient and remainder together mean. If you want to get 1.8 you need to perform floating point division which is done by ensuring that at least one of the operands to the division operator is a floating point type (float, double, etc). So, doing `9.0/5.0` will give you a float result. If, however, you assign that result to an `int` variable, you will lose the floating point, and be left with just 1.

Comment: but for example if my formula insist on being an integer 9/5, is it possible to still return the results as above?

Comment: If you want the quotient and remainder when dividing 2 integers, `%` will give the remainder, `/` will give the quotient. The title of your question is to obtain these two separate values, so why are you asking how to get 1.8?

Comment: No. `9/5` will be performed using integer division since both operands are integers. The result will therefore be an integer. What is the problem with writing your formula as `9.0/5.0 * c + 32` instead of `9/5 * c + 32`?

Comment: I was just wondering if i can get both of them together as 1. but it seems like i only can get it via this method      9/5 * static_cast<double>(c) + 32.

Comment: Anyway, since `9/5` is `1.8` why don't you just write the formula as `1.8 * c + 32`? This avoids the problem that you seem to have in understanding this.

Comment: yeah, you're right. i'm just curious to know if it still works the previous way or not. but of course i know i could just write as 1.8. but thanks for your help. appreciate it.

Comment: Well it doesn't work, as explained over and over again, because `9/5` will give an integer.